How to Seed Data from JSON Files in Laravel?
I have some JSON files, and I want to use them to seed my database in Laravel. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Specifically, I want to:

Migrate the database tables required for the JSON data.

Use Laravel's Seeder class to read the JSON files and insert the data into the database.


For context, here is an example of the JSON file (data.json) I’m working with. It contains an array of user data:
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "age": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "jane@example.com",
    "age": 25
  }
]


in your seeder class you can first read the json data from the file and write your logic to map those data with your database table. Then using eloquent or raw query you can store that data into the table.

What exactly is the problem? Migrating the database, such that the proper columns are created, or reading the data itself?

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Path to your JSON file
        $jsonFile = base_path('database/seeders/data.json');

        // Read and decode the JSON file
        $jsonData = json_decode(File::get($jsonFile), true);

        // Insert data into the database
        DB::table('users')->insert($jsonData);
    }
}

